# How to Decrease FastScroll Thumb Size

Tags: android, android-layout, android-styles

***LEFT IMAGE*** - **This is the size I need on my Fast Scroll Thumb(small).**
***RIGHT IMAGE*** - **This is the size I am getting(very big).**
[image: This is the size i want to my scroll thumb]
[image]

*MyFragment.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"></ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

*style.xml*

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/ColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/ColorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Main" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/ColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/ColorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:fastScrollThumbDrawable">@drawable/ic_datejumper</item>
    <item name="android:fastScrollTrackDrawable">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Pref" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/ColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/ColorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

I tried all the ways I found over internet and stackoverflow
*If you want to check, the left image is from Google Photos app*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found an unusual answer 
I placed the png in drawables-xhdpi folder and that did the trick